# Upload files to a directory on the server and write the path on a table of the database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm developing a service request software and I need to work with the attachments of the senders.

I would like to know how I can save uploaded files in a directory on my server and only record the file path in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get your attachment as BLOB you can use this function to write it to a file in your directory:

```sql
Function BLOB2FILE (mBLOB BLOB, mDir VARCHAR2, mFile VARCHAR2) RETURN VarChar2
IS
BEGIN
  Declare
    utlFile       UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    utlBuffer     RAW(32767);
    utlAmount     BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
    utlPos        INTEGER := 1;
    utlBlobLen    INTEGER;
    mRet          VarChar2(100);
  Begin
    utlBlobLen := DBMS_LOB.GetLength(mBLOB);
    utlFile := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(mDir, mFile,'wb', 32767);
--
    WHILE utlPos <= utlBlobLen LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.READ(mBLOB, utlAmount, utlPos, utlBuffer);
      UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(utlFile, utlBuffer, TRUE);
      utlPos := utlPos + utlAmount;
    END LOOP;
--
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(utlFile);
    mRet := 'OK - file created ' || mFile;
    RETURN mRet;
  Exception
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(utlFile) THEN
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(utlFile);
      END IF;
      mRet := 'ERR - CLOB_ETL.BLOB2FILE message  ' || Chr(10) || SQLERRM;
      RETURN mRet;
  End;
END BLOB2FILE;
```

The path of your DIRECTORY object could be fetched from all_directories and then inserted/updated in the database table...

```sql
Select DIRECTORY_PATH From ALL_DIRECTORIES Where DIRECTORY_NAME = :your_directory_name
```

Regards...